# Chrome displaying characters shifted by one letter but markup shows correct content

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I'm seeing some very odd behaviour using Chrome to view content of a website I curate. On some pages only, I see a few words that are displayed shifted by one character. For example, the word "Syntax" is shifted to "Tzouby", but the word "Example" is shifted to "Eybnqmf" (note the first letter remains unaffected). The markup shows the correct value "Syntax" but the Chrome browser displays "Tzouby".

If I refresh, sometimes the display issue goes away.

The kerning (spacing) is rendered as if the characters are the expected ones (note the word "Eybnqmf" the "mf" overlap in spacing as if it were the letters "le"), but the actual characters displayed are just... off by one.

This doesn't happen on any other browser (I checked IE and Firefox), and happens frequently but not consistently (around 80% of the time) on Chrome.

**What do I do to permanently make the content render correctly? Are there any other details I can check to troubleshoot this issue?**

Here's what I see (highlights on the area of interest):

[image: Incorrect, character-shifted view which doesn't match the markup]

Here's what I see after I refresh a few times:

[image: Correct view]

Here's what the HTML Markup looks like in both cases:

```html
<h3 id="get">HTML GET</h3>
<p>If you provide the name of the UDT and the internal key of a record in that table, then the B1WebAPI web service will return an XML representation of that record.</p>
<p>Syntax: <code class="code">/udt/<em>&lt;UDT-name&gt;</em>/<em>&lt;UDT-key&gt;</em>.aspx</code></p>
<p>Example: <code class="code">/udt/myCustomTable/10000.aspx</code></p>
<p>If you just provide the name of the UDT without a key, then the B1WebAPI web service will return all of the records in that UDT in XML format.</p>
```

This issue is just plain baffling...

Comment: Must be Windows since you're using IE, but which version of Chrome? Have you tried older or newer (nightly) versions?

Comment: @Karan 43.0.2357.81 I noticed the issue, updated to this version (but I didn't note what the version was before I updated). Standard stable release, not the nightly builds or anything.

Answer (score 0):

This really sounds like the same issue reported here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115028/jlabel-text-is-garbled

So - try deleting c:\windows\system32\fntcache.dat and see if it helps.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).